# What is the VB.NET equivalent to this C# code?

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

VB.NET equivalent to this C# code?

```
    ctx.Load(site,
                x => x.Lists.Where(l => l.Title != null));
```

I've tried

```
 ctx.Load(site, Function(x) x.Lists.Where(Function(l) l.Title IsNot Nothing))
```

but this errors with `"The expression (Convert(l.Title) != null) is not supported."`

Thoughts

Comment: Title is a Property that happens to be a String type

Answer (score 2):

if Title is string try use IsNullOrEmpty();

or

Nullable(Of T).HasValue if Title is Nullable

or

```
Sub Main()

        Dim list As New List(Of A)

        Dim a1 As New A
        a1.Title = "sqws"
        Dim a2 As New A
        a2.Title = Nothing


        list.Add(a1)
        list.Add(a2)

        Dim q = From c In list Where c.Title IsNot Nothing

    End Sub



    Public Class A

        Dim t As String

        Public Property Title() As String
            Get
                Title = t
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                t = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
```

Comment: I've tried these and 1) type is not nullable its a String.  2) cannot seem to do string comparisons in the lambda statement...

Answer (score 2):

This may be cheating, but I have used Reflector in the past to decompile my C# code and then display it as other .NET languages just to see how they would look as I am most fluent in C#

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [IsNothing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz(VS.71).aspx) function?

```
ctx.Load(site, Function(x) x.Lists.Where(Function(l) Not IsNothing(l.Title)))
```

**EDIT:**

Now that you've specified that Title is a String, then you should use the IsNullOrEmpty function.

```
ctx.Load(site, Function(x) x.Lists.Where(Function(l) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(l.Title)))
```

Comment: when I try this in the Lambda expression I receive an error stating that the IsNnothing member cannot be used in the expression...

Answer (score 0):

This really should work:

```
ctx.Load(site, Function(x) x.Lists.Where(Function(l) l.Title.IsNullOrEmpty = False))
```

If it does not, let me know the error message.